# How Backlit LCD Moniter Works, How it Looks Without a Backlight

Tags: lcd, display, monitor

I'm thinking about repurposing an lcd backlit monitor's front panel as an 'overlay' type panel over something else without a backlight.
My understanding of the function of a backlit monitor that the front panel on an LCD monitor filters the backlight as specified by the input values telling what pixels to let light through on.

what I am wondering is this: if I were to remove the filtering panel and put in the image input for the inverse of a black circle as shown below, would the panel perform as a more-or-less transparent window with the circle portion visible?
[image: visual representation of moniter image input]

Feel free to correct anything I misunderstand about the general ideas expressed above, I'm very new to the topic.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. LCD panels are built by robots as accurate as .0001" or .0039mm. Just touch the up-front mask (that stops adjacent pixels from bleeding into each other) and it is ruined for good. Think of it as a large integrated circuit. Please find something more rational to do.

Comment: Given compatible light source spectra this should work to some degree, but bear in mind that the human eye has variable sensitivity to different colors of light, any given light source produces a different intensity across wavelengths, and the same is true when comparing filters, so if you are considering stacking a monitor panel over another, you may have color shift and need to compensate in software.  One other thing is that monitor panels often include polarizing layers, and IIRC the polarization direction of these layers must be compatible, or you could attempt to remove one polarizer.